# ls -l shows file size 0 of files in /proc, but cat produces content

Tags: linux, filesystems, centos, ls

```
# cat /proc/version
Linux version 2.6.18-308.8.2.el5.028stab101.1 (root@rhel5-build-x64) (gcc version 4.1.2 20080704 (Red Hat 4.1.2-46)) #1 SMP Sun Jun 24 20:25:35 MSD 2012
# ls -l /proc/version
-r--r--r-- 1 root root 0 Aug 22 10:07 /proc/version
```

The file size is reported as 0, but it has contents. How does this work?

Is it because `/proc` is some kind of virtual file system?

Which command could show the exact size of files in `/proc`?

Comment: this question is not suitable to be there, it's not a shopping or buying recommendation one:(

Comment: As I said, it's an operating system question (how to do something in the OS), and not a code-related question. See the FAQ, as I suggested before.

Comment: but it's a linux related question, you know linux is a bit different from others, like windows, there are lots of topics in linux, but has nothing to do with digital equipment and shopping recommendation, also it have nothing to do with mobile phones, so it will be a fault to move this topic to superuser

Comment: Linux is an operating system. Your question is not code or programming-tool or library related, and is therefore off-topic. I've referred you to the FAQ for the third time now. This isn't a debate, and arguing isn't going to change my mind. The question is off-topic here, in the same way a question about how to adjust the color on your monitor or how to set up your new keyboard would be. It's **not** a programming question, and is off-topic. If you would read the FAQ I've mentioned (now **4** times), it might help. I could downvote; I didn't; I even upvoted the answer. Still not on-topic.

Comment: it have something to do with filesystem, dude, it's linux command line, it should not be put together with mp3 or shopping suggestion:( this is a programmer question :) so it should be here:)

Comment: For the last time! It's not a **programming question**. Superuser is for operating system questions, not just for shopping o0r mp3 questions. If you really insist, I can downvote this for being a poor programming question as well as vote to close it as off-topic. I think you misunderstand - users decide what's on-topic here and what isn't, and I've cast my vote as it not being appropriate. You're not going to convince me otherwise, so you may as well stop trying to do so. IMO, it's off-topic here. You obviously don't agree, since you posted it here in the first place. Discussion over. :-)

Comment: in fact people who want to install windows, or buy a mp3, or how to plug the batter from his mobile phone would not like linux questions, so this question should be better here, and it's not reasonable to move it to superuser:(

Comment: I've referred you to the FAQ for what questions are proper here several times. If you refuse to read them, that's not my problem. I've voted to close this question; I've said all I'm going to say. This discussion is **over**. It's wrong to ask here because it's wrong to ask here, no matter how hard you try to say differently. Superuser is for people who have questions about installing windows, or getting file sizes in Linux, or how to do things in OSX; **exactly** the kind of question you're asking. Once more, **READ THE FAQ HERE** to see why. I'm done here; I can flag for a mod if you want.

Comment: Ken, procfs is a core part of the Linux ABI, and understanding how it works is an important part of linux programming.  The question is simple, but not an inappropriate one to be asked by a beginning programmer.  This absurdist flame war, on the other hand, is a disgrace and you should be ashamed of yourself.

Comment: @AndyRoss: You are the one seeing a flame war. I see someone (rightly, no doubt about it) pointing out that the question is off-topic for Stack Overflow, and on-topic for Super User. hugemeow seems to have misunderstood what Super User is, and is technically at fault here, which is certainly OK for new users, but he/she should be modest enough to realize this as well when seeking help.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It's because you're in the `proc` filesystem. See more info on [what procfs is](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Procfs).

> /proc/version, containing the Linux kernel version, distribution number, gcc version number (used to build the kernel) and any other pertinent information relating to the version of the kernel currently running

Those aren't real files. It's a convenient way to show process information as a file hierachy.

---

EDIT:

> i know it's unreal, but what i should do if i want to know its size?

You're not getting it from `ls`, but you can try using `wc`:

```
# wc -c /proc/version
138 /proc/version
```

Comment: i know it's unreal, but what i should do if i want to know its size?

Comment: @hugemeow I've edited my answer

Comment: i want a list which can tell me the size of files, not just a single one:(

Comment: @hugemeow then use find: `find /proc/ -maxdepth 1 -type f -exec wc -c {} +`

Comment: it's really boring to type such a long command, is there any easier way to do this?

Comment: @hugemeow write a script and call it `a`, that's real short.